# Nginx certbot SSL not working with Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, nginx, cloudflare, certbot

Have recently moved to CloudFlare as I wanted a DNS service that provided DNS credentials for certbot to generate a wildcard SSL certificate.

However, I am struggling to get a basic SSL Nginx setup running.

**Background:**

1. DNS resolution works fine. (When I just have an Nginx HTTP server block, the website loads insecurely over HTTP)
2. Can connect to website via direct IP with HTTPS address (not via CloudFlare IP). It gives an invalid cert warning but still connects.
3. `openssl s_client -connect property-connect.co.uk:443 -servername property-connect.co.uk` seems to indicate the SSL certificate is fine

**Steps:**

1. Ran `certbot --nginx` specified include both domains (www.property-connect.co.uk property-connect.co.uk)
2. `sudo nginx -t` was successful
3. `sudo nginx -s reload`

**nginx.conf**

```
events {

}

http {
  server {
    server_name www.property-connect.co.uk property-connect.co.uk;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:700;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/property-connect.co.uk-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/property-connect.co.uk-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  }
}
```

Any thoughts as to what I am missing with this basic config?

Comment: You have not really specified what problem do you have... CloudFlare gives error 521 and says the server is not reachable (from them). Do you see anything in the logfiles? Did you try to ask CloudFlare? Any kind of firewall on your host?

Answer (score 3):

Your current certificate for this domain issued and managed by Cloudflare itself, not by your CertBot/Nginx:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect property-connect.co.uk:443 -servername property-connect.co.uk  </dev/null 2>&1 | grep ^issuer
issuer=C = US, ST = CA, L = San Francisco, O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", CN = CloudFlare Inc ECC CA-2
```

I guess this is because you have proxied traffic via Cloudflare to your host
[image]

You should switch your domain to `DNS only` and then you will able to connect directly to your Nginx without Cloudflare reverse-proxying.

Comment: I do want to keep the reverse proxy though to protect source IP

Comment: @mgibson You have to choose to use Cloudflare proxy for https or use Certbot with https on Nginx side.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to change the Cloudflare SSL setting from

`Websites > example.com > SSL/TLS > Overview > Flexible`

to

`Websites > example.com > SSL/TLS > Overview > Full`.

[image]